Chrome Extension: Trying to retrieve text from an HTML SVG Use tag
Given the following HTML code:
<div>
  <div class="eventMsg">
    <span class="logText playerName" style="color: rgb(153, 37, 31);">red</span>        
    <span class="logText"> built a </span>
    <svg height="20" width="20" overflow="visible">
      <use href="#settlement-def-red" style="transform: translate(13px, 11px) scale(0.06);"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

I'm building a Chrome extension that takes data similar to the above to build a display in a side panel. I need to get to the words "settlement-def-red" in the svg->use tag so I know what the player built. I'm able to get the text "red built a" by using ".textContent on the element, but can't get any deeper than that.
I'm working in Typescript, building with VS Code, but I can't find the right code to get to that line and extract the "href" text. Any ideas? -Thanks!

Have you tried .getAttribute('href') on the element to extract it's attributes?

Note the optional chaining ?.


const href = document.querySelector('.eventMsg svg use')?. getAttribute('href');
console.log(href)
<div>
  <div class="eventMsg">
    <span class="logText playerName" style="color: rgb(153, 37, 31);">red</span>        
    <span class="logText"> built a </span>
    <svg height="20" width="20" overflow="visible">
      <use href="#settlement-def-red" style="transform: translate(13px, 11px) scale(0.06);"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>



PS: If you use .href instead of getAttribute('href') you will get two values, the baseVal and the animVal.

Thank you! Your response got me very close. When I paste it into VS Code, the compiler gives me this error: "Property 'href' does not exist on type 'Element'." I adjusted it to "document.querySelector('.eventMsg svg use')?.getAttribute("href");" and got the href attribute of the "use" tag in a very usable string. With a quick substring and split, I got right down to the word I need! If you want to update your response, I'll mark it as the correct response. -Thanks!!
